# Call SOAP API In Node js and getting error

Tags: node.js, soap

I am Using Following code to call Soap API In node js But I am not geting responce back but when use this api in java i get back responce properly with above xml data* .Below is my code which i am using . please suggst me right code .My code is below ,I am using npm module soap to work on it

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
        var client = new Client();

        // request and response additional configuration 
        var args = {

            headers: { "test-header": "client-api" },
            data: "<xml><NMFIIService><service_request><appln_id>MFS37314 </appln_id><broker_code>ARN-37314</broker_code><password>QC1RA3CJ</password><user_type>Broker</user_type><broker_loc_code>M3</broker_loc_code><iin>5011164069</iin><sub_trxn_type>N</sub_trxn_type><poa>Y</poa><trxn_acceptance>OL</trxn_acceptance><demat_user>N</demat_user><dp_id></dp_id><bank>ICI</bank><ac_no>017701520489</ac_no><ifsc_code>ICIC0000177</ifsc_code><sub_broker_arn_code></sub_broker_arn_code><sub_broker_code></sub_broker_code><euin_opted>Y</euin_opted><euin>E049164</euin><trxn_execution>Y</trxn_execution><remarks>test</remarks><payment_mode>OL</payment_mode><billdesk_bank>ICI</billdesk_bank><instrm_bank></instrm_bank><instrm_ac_no></instrm_ac_no><instrm_no></instrm_no><instrm_amount>1</instrm_amount><instrm_date></instrm_date><instrm_branch></instrm_branch><instrm_charges></instrm_charges><micr></micr><rtgs_code></rtgs_code><neft_ifsc></neft_ifsc><advisory_charge></advisory_charge><dd_charge></dd_charge><cheque_deposit_mode></cheque_deposit_mode><debit_amount_type></debit_amount_type><nominee_flag>C</nominee_flag><no_of_nominee>1</no_of_nominee><nominee1_name>BHAVNA KHATRI</nominee1_name><nominee1_dob></nominee1_dob><nominee1_addr1>C-5/5 SCOND FLOOR ARCEE CITY SECTOR 52 GURGAON</nominee1_addr1><nominee1_addr2></nominee1_addr2><nominee1_addr3></nominee1_addr3><nominee1_city>GURGAON</nominee1_city><nominee1_state></nominee1_state><nominee1_pincode></nominee1_pincode><nominee1_relation>SPOUSE</nominee1_relation><nominee1_percent>100</nominee1_percent><nominee1_guard_name></nominee1_guard_name><nominee1_guard_pan></nominee1_guard_pan><nominee2_name></nominee2_name><nominee2_dob></nominee2_dob><nominee2_relation></nominee2_relation><nominee2_percent></nominee2_percent><nominee2_guard_name></nominee2_guard_name><nominee2_guard_pan></nominee2_guard_pan><nominee3_Name></nominee3_Name><nominee3_dob></nominee3_dob><nominee3_relation></nominee3_relation><nominee3_percent></nominee3_percent><nominee3_guard_name></nominee3_guard_name><nominee3_guard_pan></nominee3_guard_pan><sip_paymech></sip_paymech><sip_micr_no></sip_micr_no><sip_bank></sip_bank><sip_branch></sip_branch><sip_instrm_no></sip_instrm_no><sip_acc_no></sip_acc_no><sip_ac_type></sip_ac_type><sip_ifsc_code></sip_ifsc_code><umrn></umrn><ach_amt></ach_amt><ach_fromdate></ach_fromdate><ach_enddate></ach_enddate><until_cancelled></until_cancelled><Return_paymnt_flag>Y</Return_paymnt_flag><Client_callback_url>http://m.investwell.in/hcver3b/pages/netbanking.jsp</Client_callback_url><trans_count>1</trans_count></service_request><childtrans><amc>128</amc><folio></folio><product_code>EFGPGGR</product_code><reinvest>Z</reinvest><amount>1</amount><sip_from_date></sip_from_date><sip_end_date></sip_end_date><sip_freq></sip_freq><sip_amount>1</sip_amount><sip_period_day></sip_period_day></childtrans></NMFIIService></xml>",
                requestConfig: {
                timeout: 1000, //request timeout in milliseconds 
                noDelay: true, //Enable/disable the Nagle algorithm 
                keepAlive: true, //Enable/disable keep-alive functionalityidle socket. 
                keepAliveDelay: 1000 //and optionally set the initial delay before the first keepalive probe is sent 
            },
            responseConfig: {
                timeout: 1000 //response timeout 
            }
        };


        client.get("https://www.nsenmf.com/NMFIITrxnService/NMFTrxnService/PURCHASETRXN", args, function (data, response) {
            // parsed response body as js object 
            console.log(data);
            // raw response 
            console.log(response);
        });
```

**And   i am not getting response from Their site which method i should try please suggest me 
And i am getting below error
**

```
<Buffer ef bb bf 3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3d 22 75 74 66 2d 38 22 3f 3e 0d 0a 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 ... >
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: true,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: true,
     reading: false,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: false,
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function] ],
     timeout: [Function],
     data: [Function],
     error: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: 
   TLSSocket {
     _tlsOptions: 
      { pipe: null,
        secureContext: [Object],
        isServer: false,
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        session: undefined,
        NPNProtocols: undefined,
        ALPNProtocols: undefined,
        requestOCSP: undefined },
     _secureEstablished: true,
     _securePending: false,
     _newSessionPending: false,
     _controlReleased: true,
     _SNICallback: null,
     servername: null,
     npnProtocol: undefined,
     alpnProtocol: false,
     authorized: true,
     authorizationError: null,
     encrypted: true,
     _events: 
      { close: [Object],
        end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        secure: [Function],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
        timeout: [Object] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'www.nsenmf.com',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: true,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: true,
     _bytesDispatched: 3021,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: undefined,
     _server: null,
     ssl: null,
     _requestCert: true,
     _rejectUnauthorized: true,
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 

  responseUrl: 'https://www.nsenmf.com',
  read: [Function] }


I am not trying other code . Please suggest me right way to achieve it
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a GET, which means that any data that you set for the body will not be passed to the server that you are calling. Try switching to `client.post` instead of `client.get`

For more information, see [the documentation for node-rest-client](https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client#passing-args-to-registered-methods)

Additionally, you're trying to call a SOAP service using a REST component. While it's still possible, traditionally you need to add things such as a SOAPAction and construct your SOAP envelope yourself, whereas using a dedicated SOAP component - such as [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) - will mean you can focus on consuming the service without worrying too much about the request structure.

Comment: Sir i have tried this one also .but same error occurs

Comment: Without knowing more about the service you're calling, it's hard to know where you're going wrong other than you definitely need to perform a POST, not a GET.

You're using a REST client to call a SOAP service, so if a SOAPAction header is required then you'll need to add that, maybe the outer <xml> tag isn't required, maybe there are other headers you need. 

It might not be a bad idea to switch the component you are using to a SOAP one such as [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) and go from there.